# Can`t move element on setInterval function

Tags: javascript

I have a small image that may change his background-position-x on hover event. And stop moving on mouseleave. But even with setInterval my fuctuin run just 1 time. Here`s my code. Could someone help me?

```
let wave = document.querySelector('.wave');

wave.onmouseover = moveWave();

function moveWave() {
    setInterval(function () {
        wave.style.backgroundPositionX  += 10 + 'px';
    }, 100)
}
```

Comment: `wave.onmouseover = moveWave()` should be `wave.onmouseover = moveWave`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with below line:
wave.style.backgroundPositionX  += 10 + 'px';

After first call, the wave.style.backgroundPositionX will be:
10px

After next call, the wave.style.backgroundPositionX will be:
10px10px -> which is incorrect format.

The right way is:

```
var count = 10;
let wave = document.querySelector('.wave');
wave.onmouseover = moveWave();

function moveWave() {
    setInterval(function () {
        count += 10;
        wave.style.backgroundPositionX  = count + 'px';
    }, 100)
}
```

Comment: Ty, this works. But it works when the page ready. And must work on hover event...

Comment: function starts on hover event, but i can`t clearInterval on mouseleave. Help me please

Comment: var count = 10;
let wave = document.querySelector('.wave');
wave.onmouseover = moveWave();
wave.onmouseleave = moveLeave();
var id;

function moveWave() {
    id = setInterval(function () {
        count += 10;
        wave.style.backgroundPositionX  = count + 'px';
    }, 100)
}

function moveLeave() {
  clearInterval(id);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 10;
let wave = document.querySelector('.wave');
wave.onmouseover = moveWave();
wave.onmouseleave = moveLeave();
var id;

function moveWave() {
    id = setInterval(function () {
        count += 10;
        wave.style.backgroundPositionX  = count + 'px';
    }, 100)
}

function moveLeave() {
  clearInterval(id);
}
```